# Connection_refused when trying to use MySQL and node.js. When using cmd it does work

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, ionic-framework, phpmyadmin

I created a server.js file which looks like this.

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port);
console.log('todo list RESTful API server started on: ' + port)

var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "**",
  password: "**",
  database: "test"
});
app.get('/nodeapi/getimg',function(req,res){

    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        con.query("SELECT * FROM images", function (err, result, fields) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(result[1].image);;
        });
      })})
```

When I run this file in my command terminal I get the correct result.

When I create a http.get function like this for my ionic app:

```
getimg(){ 
  var url = 'http://localhost:3000/nodeapi/getimg';
  this.http.get(url).subscribe(responseData => console.log(responseData));}
```

I get an error saying net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I have looked everywhere but cannot seem to find it. I am using phpmyadmin for the database. Would anyone please be so kind to explain to me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you defining your express port as `8080` in your `start` command or some other way? If not, you're making a request against the wrong port since it would be `3000` if not defined (as indicated on line 3 of your example). Please provide additional examples of the log contents from startup of your app as well as errors.

Comment: I made a typo that should be 3000 indeed. I get an error message in my log saying: Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:2500/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's trying to get favicon on 2500 (I don't use much angular or ionic so maybe something specific to those frameworks). The underlying problem however is `CORS` support which is very annoying with `localhost`. You'll need several changes. I'll add an example as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this example a try. Also, do you expect more than one result from your query? If not you will want to use `result[0]` not `1` to get the first (and maybe only) result (located at index 0).

```js
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "**",
  password: "**",
  database: "test"
});

app.get('/nodeapi/getimg', function(req, res) {
  con.connect(function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;
    con.query("SELECT * FROM images", function(err, result, fields) {
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(result[1].image);
      res.send(result[1].image); // send the value back to the caller.
    });
  })
})

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Comment: With this way the first time I do the api call I do not get any results but only after that I do. Would you know why this is the case? I thought the query is only used after the connection is made so that should not be the issue.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the specifics of the requesting client. Also, your results might vary from environment to environment. CORS can be very complicated with many variables. For example: when you move to production, your requests might be originating from the same domain as your API. As a result some things work better, with fewer configurations required, because you're no longer making cross-domain requests. My guess is that your requesting app might be doing a [pre-flight check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) first.